# C# Mongodb Cannot Find Existing Collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, database-connection

I am using version 1.6 of the mongodb driver for C# because of a legacy program.
I can create the connection to the server with the proper port and database as I would normally expect.

```
connectionstring = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?safe=true"
database = "gear"
_server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
_database = _server[database];
```

Everything here seems to work fine, but _database claims that it has 0 collections. Which is contrary to commandline when I log into the mongodb

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017
>>> use gear
>>> show collections
gear
user
```

Comment: You are trying to query from the code, correct?

Comment: yes, and I finally found the issue. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending a lot of time tinkering with mongodb and my C# project, I found that this issue was caused from using a different version of mongodb than what the database was created in. Somewhere along the line the mongodb installed was updated and the database was never changed so that driver for .NET was having issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From there... Create a new instance of the client and try to query the collection... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that did not fix the issue either. I think that is just a more fanciful way of the code I posted above.

Comment: Kurt, why do you have the '/?safe=true' in your connection string? I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Honestly, that is how it was when I picked up the project. Last time it was worked on was 2009.